# Bug in the data import wizard

Tags: civicontribute, import

We need to daily export all donation data from CommitChange and import the data to civicrm using the data import wizard. So the process is:

Map the appropriate donation fields to civicrm fields and then import donation information from the CSV file. In each case the name of the donation field is "Total Amount."

According to CiviCRM the donation data is successfully imported. However, in every record, the amount of the donation is stored in CiviCRM as "$0". I do not have the coding skills needed to fix the bug or to write a custom script to import the data, so any help is appreciated.

Drupal 7.53 with CiviCRM 4.7.14
also tested on CiviCRM 4.7.13 on a different Drupal site

Comment: it will be nice to add here the CiviCRM versions you have tested on and indicated if you are using Drupal, Joomla or Wordpress

Comment: quick thoughts. can you set up a simplified version of this on demo to confirm the same problem there? also have you verified the 'format' of that field in your csv? also have you tried doing an export of the data from civi for the same fields just to verify you are feeding it the expected data formats?

Comment: That was exactly the hint I needed. The problem is that CiviCRM exports (and imports) data in a CSV file in which every cell is formatted "general," while CommitChange exports donation amount as formatted "currency." Problem solved. Now, I wonder if the CiviCRM import wizard could be improved to give me a signal that it expects all CSV data to be formatted "general"?

Comment: @AndrewHimes I'm glad that you solved this.  Could you please add this as an answer to help other people that may have the same problem in future.

Comment: while it was more of a Hint than an Answer, I popped mine out as an answer as it sounds useful. Andrew can do the same with his finding. glad it was a useful hint

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an export of the data from civi of the fields you want to import just to verify you have the data in the expected data formats

EDIT (from Andrew's comment above)

The problem is that CiviCRM exports (and imports) data in a CSV file in which every cell is formatted "general," while CommitChange exports donation amount as formatted "currency." Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought:
Total Amount should just be an integer - so don't import $8 but 8.

Doing this daily is a real chore - CiviCRM has was to help automate such tasks - like civicrm rest API.